# Conditional Formatting lags behind (visually)

Tags: excel, vba

I insert code in a worksheet if there isn't any code present yet to auto-update conditional formatting. This works fine for some sheets but others lag behind visually.

This is a random selected cell whereupon I insert the code and conditional formatting into the sheet:
[image: starting position]
It's just to keep track where I am in bigger datasets when working in different workbooks/programs.

For this worksheet (and I've had this issue before but don't know how to reproduce), the "initial"  state lags behind in certain areas as seen below
[image: lags behind]

If I however use the two last lines in the code or I scroll down (to where the problem isn't visible anymore) and scroll back up, the visual glitch is gone.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo skipEnd
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Application.CutCopyMode = False Then
            Application.Calculate
        End If
    End If
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
skipEnd:
End Sub
```

`On Error GoTo skipEnd` is solely there to stop an overflow error when selecting the entire sheet.

It's always the same rows as well when it does occur, regardless of which column/cell I started in. There's no split or anything I can think of that could throw a wrench in my otherwise happy little QoL update.
Does anyone have an idea as to how to prevent this rather than the need for a flicker of `Application.ScreenUpdating`? (especially since this only happens sporadically)

Ps: I'm aware people ask for a reproducible issue, just hoping others have stumbled upon a solution rather than a patch.

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` should be at the start of your sub not after you have done the calculation. Also do you need to calculate the entire application (all workbooks open) or just this sheet

Comment: You're right, `Target.Calculate` is plenty for this particular piece. Placing the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to the top also prevents the flicker I was seeing. So you've actually helped with making it an easy solution to the excel issue, you can post it as an answer and if nobody finds the actual cause of it, I'll give you the wee checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

`CELL("rij")` only updates whenever a calculation takes place. This is not the case if you simply select a new row.

Add `Target.Calculate` to the `Worksheet_SelectionChange`-event - then `CELL("rij")` gets updated as well.

Comment: As you can see, Application.Calculate already is in the SelectionChange event, adding Target.Calculate did not change this strange behavior. The Target.Calculate is however a whole lot better than me using Application.Calculate as Chill60 mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Ahh - sorry. Maybe calculation doesn't take place due to your IF-conditions?

Comment: The calculation goes fine even when only selecting a new row (the new row gets selected), it's when I go off the starting column that it gets tricky with those particular rows not updating.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything. Don't use Application.ScreenUpdating in Worksheet_SelectionChange.
Just save the book under a different name with Save as, close it, open it  and everything will be fixed.

In the above way I was able to fix something similar. On yet another occasion I had to delete these two rules (which form a cross) by clearing from the menu all the rules on the sheet. When I wrote them back they worked fine.

A third way to fix this problem is: 1)delete the rules of the sheet 2) change the height of cells (i my case set it to 30), 3) Set the height back (in my case 15,75)  4) rewrite the rules

Comment: I saved it under a different name, closed and reopened it to no avail. I thought at first it was fixed as you said but the code was still inserted with `Application.ScreenUpdating`. Besides that, this involves a lot more manual work than inserting the two mentioned lines. Deleting the conditional formatting rules and manually typing them back keeps the issue at hand. What a finical problem.

Comment: I've also copied the Usedrange to a new workbook which worked fine from there on. Not sure if a singular worksheet can get corrupted but it's starting to look like it.

Comment: Ok, try setting the height of all lines to a certain height, if the book was created on another system it might cause this kind of problem. Q: what you mean "code was still inserted with Application.ScreenUpdating"?

Comment: I meant that my macro inserts code in the Sheet (i.e. it inserts a Worksheet_SelectionChange event sub) but I hadn't taken out the two lines. I'll try your suggestion tomorrow, omw home now.

Comment: Setting the height of all lines fiddled a bit with how it's shown but the problem remains.

Comment: I would like you to check one more thing: When you create a new Sheet, is the font the same as the default one in Options?

Comment: Yep, all the same as it always is, no changes there. When I think about differences from other files, it'd be that this is a copy paste from a file that's saved in the network, one that's saved automatically, but other than that it's exactly the same as any other file I use on the regular.